# unable to delete redis key using JMeter SSH command

Tags: redis, jmeter

I am unable to delete redis key using JMeter SSH command sampler. below is the command. Please help.

redis-cli del "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x17POSTACTIVATIONconfigmap"

Comment: Please add more information to the question such as the error message are you getting

Answer (score 0):

You can use configuration like:

[image]

As per [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/del) it should return `1` (number of removed keys)

[image]

The whole sequence: [LRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/lrange) -> DEL -> LRANGE

[image]

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)